# Making an effiecient combining and fill-up algorithm

Tags: python, list, algorithm, sorting

I have a list of suitcases, each `suitcase` has a `name` and a `weight` associated to it. I want to write a function that groups these suitcases in a way together that their weights always forms a `multiple of 8` and returns a list of the formed tuples. If there is a suitcase that can not be formed to a multiple of 8ths then that suitcase gets "filled up" with 1s (this should only be the last resort).  So for example:

```
sc1 = suitcase("sc1", 5)
sc2 = suitcase("sc2", 1)
sc3 = suitcase("sc3", 3)
sc4 = suitcase("sc4", 14)
sc5 = suitcase("sc5", 4)
sc6 = suitcase("sc6", 1)
sc7 = suitcase("sc7", 8)
sclist = [sc1,sc2,sc3,sc4,sc5,sc6,sc7]

sorted_tuple = sort_suitcases(sclist)

sorted_tuple = [(sc7),(sc1,sc3),(sc4,sc2,sc6),(sc5,{1,1,1,1})] # this is obviously only one of many possible combinations.
# having only one big tuple would obviously also be a solution
```

My approach would be looping over each value and loop over each other value left in the list and see if their weight combined is `%8`, but I feel like this approach would be not very efficient with big data sets. Am I missing something?

Comment: This sounds like the [bin-packing problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_packing_problem)

Comment: @Stef: That has bins of pre-specified sizes; this has bins whose sizes all have a certain *property* but not specific *sizes*.

Comment: After thinking about it some more: it looks like the number of 1s which you have to use to "fill up" the last bin is a constant: it does not depend at all on how you split the numbers. So, the solution "put all numbers in the same bin" is not worse than any other solution. Do you have other criteria to decide that a solution is worse than another?

Comment: @Stef It probably would be the most suitable solution to have all numbers in the "same bin" for my use case now that I think about it. But no there is no other criteria.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Partition the suitcases into 8 groups, based on their weight % 8.
2. Pair up members of the groups to make sums that are multiples of 8: 1 & 7, 2 & 6, 3 & 5, 4 & itself.
3. Deal with those that couldn't be paired off (larger groups & filling-up)

Comment: This appears to assume that the groups must be pairs.

Comment: @Stef: Hence the addition of #3.

Comment: i worked it out, thanks for the tips